# Use rust_xlsxwriter `write_with_format()` in isolation

Tags: rust, rust-xlsxwriter

I have an array of numbers, like "40,000.123", and I want to format it with a formatting string, like "YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm AM/PM".

How do I do that in rust_xlsxwriter? I don't need a full workbook instance.

Comment: `rust_xlsxwriter` and Excel don't format numbers/dates when saving to a file. They just write the unchanged f64 number along with the user specified format string. Excel uses the format to change the way the number is **displayed** in the UI. If you want to format numbers like Excel you can do it with [`chrono`](https://docs.rs/chrono/latest/chrono/index.html) but it would be with standard Unix [`strftime`](https://docs.rs/rust_xlsxwriter/latest/rust_xlsxwriter/struct.Format.html) type formatting and not the Excel type format you show in your question. If that is okay I can give an example.